# anonymous access to icinga cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, icinga, anonymous

I'm currently setting up an Icinga monitoring system, however I'm lacking the idea of how to access a specific page that asks for authentication when accessed by http, mainly the "All problems" option on Icinga.

Is there anyway I can bypass authentication (the ideia is to put that page on a rotation page displaying on my second screen)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the typical dashboard question, which has been tricky in the past.

The option you are looking for is use_authentication=0 in cgi.cfg - though, this is actually a bad idea given your current setup with authorization by your existing users and such.

There's still another method in achieving that without harming your existing install - create another apache configuration serving your Classic UI below "/icinga-dashboard" and use Satisfy Any for the authorization, e.g. your local network. Though, SetEnvIf for the REMOTE_USER will be required then too, and some more advanced apache knowledge in general (or your preferred webserver).

A more easy method (but a bit more overhead) will be installing the Classic UI as a standalone application, having their own cgis/html and only reading the data source from Icinga Core, serving only what you require.
Since we are using the Classic UI while developing Icinga2 Compatibility Layers, we finally made that happen with Icinga 1.9 release - you can install Classic UI Standalone by following this documentation: https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Setting+up+Icinga+Classic+UI+Standalone

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [check_http](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http) plugin to monitor webpage which asks you for authentication.`Check_http` plugin have such functionality to check webpage health with the parameters passed with it.

```
Ex: check_http -I <ipaddress of server> -H host_name.com -u /index.html -a username:password
```

Where,
-I = ipaddress of the server

-H = Host name

-u = url for the host(if it has). Ex: www.myhost.com/index.html

-a = for authentication.

**Define command for such**

```
 # 'check_http' command definition
    define command{
    command_name check_http_test
    command_line $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$ -a username:password
    }
```

**Define service:**

```
define service{
use local-service ; Name of service template to use
host_name hostname
service_description HTTP_AUTH
check_command check_http_test
notifications_enabled 0
}
```

Comment: I think he was asking how he would monitor an internal icinga page which was asking for authentication..

Comment: Hi,I don't want to monitor nothing..
I want to add link to the icinga all problems page on a nagvis rotation demo which means I need to access that page without it to ask for http authentication.